# How can I fill an horizontal space with spaces to force the text to begin on the next line in a moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to fill the horizontal line from de last "Paris" word (in my MWE) so that "Percent - 99.99%" could start at the beginning of the next line.

This should be the result:

```
Bsc., University xxx, Paris Paris Paris Paris Paris, 
Percent – 99.99%
...
```

I have tried \hspace but in this case (although the word "Percent..." begins at the next line) the first line does not look like the last example because the space at right is distributed along de line and the text looks like this:

```
Bsc.,    University   xxx,    Paris    Paris    Paris    Paris    Paris, 
Percent – 99.99%
...
```

What can I do??

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[unicode]{attachfile}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\firstname{Peter} 
\familyname{Peter Peter} 

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\cventry{2016--Present}{Bsc.}{University xxx}{Paris Paris Paris Paris Paris}{\textit{Percent -- 99.99\%}}{Engineering}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\newline` before `\textit` works for me:

```
\cventry{2016--Present}{Bsc.}{University xxx}{%
  Paris Paris Paris Paris Paris}{%
  \newline\textit{Percent -- 99.99\%}}{Engineering}
```